# Using [R] maps package - colouring in specific nations on a world map

Tags: r, maps

I'm trying to create a world map and color certain nations. Basically, I would like to highlight some countries in red and other countries in blue.

If someone could help me generate the basic [R] code for this, I would be very thankful!!

Comment: Searching for "R chloropleth map" will yield dividends for you, as in this top hit: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/11/choropleth-map-r-challenge.html. This has also been addressed on SO with some good answers.

Comment: Also, if you do want a more general solution than the one I provided below, typing `[r] choropleth` (rather than `[r] chloropleth`) in the SO search bar will get links to plenty of good answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not hooked on using the `maps` package, the object `wrld_simpl` in the `maptools` package can make producing this sort of map pretty easy. Here, to get you started, are a few lines of code that produce a world map in which nations whose names start with the letter "U" are colored in red:

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl, 
     col = c(gray(.80), "red")[grepl("^U", wrld_simpl@data$NAME) + 1])
```

(`wrld_simpl` is an object of class `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, and the data.frame contained in `wrld_simple@data` includes a `NAME` column that you can use to highlight whichever countries you choose.)

[image]

Comment: What if you want to highlight different countries not necessarily those whose names start with any particular letter? Thanks!