# How to create a world map in R with specific countries filled in?

Tags: r, maps, r-maptools, rworldmap

I would like to use R to generate a very basic world map with a specific set of countries filled with a red colour to indicate that they are malaria endemic countries.

I have a list of these countries in a data frame but am struggling to overlay them on a world map.

I have tried using the `wrld_simpl` object and also the `joinCountryData2Map` method in the `rworldmap` package.

I would comment on this answer to prevent addition of a possibly redundant question but I do not have enough reputation at the moment, apologies for this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102797/1470099

I am having difficulty understanding the arguments given to the `plot()` command - I wondered if there was just an easy way to tell R to plot all of the country NAMEs in my list on the `wrld_simpl` map instead of using `grepl()` etc. etc.

```
plot(wrld_simpl, 
     col = c(gray(.80), "red")[grepl("^U", wrld_simpl@data$NAME) + 1])
```

Comment: @ttmaccer, why not add that as an answer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the `rworldmap` package, you could use the following:

```
library(rworldmap)

theCountries <- c("DEU", "COD", "BFA")
# These are the ISO3 names of the countries you'd like to plot in red

malDF <- data.frame(country = c("DEU", "COD", "BFA"),
  malaria = c(1, 1, 1))
# malDF is a data.frame with the ISO3 country names plus a variable to
# merge to the map data

malMap <- joinCountryData2Map(malDF, joinCode = "ISO3",
  nameJoinColumn = "country")
# This will join your malDF data.frame to the country map data

mapCountryData(malMap, nameColumnToPlot="malaria", catMethod = "categorical",
  missingCountryCol = gray(.8))
# And this will plot it, with the trick that the color palette's first
# color is red
```

EDIT: Add other colors and include picture

```
## Create multiple color codes, with Burkina Faso in its own group
malDF <- data.frame(country = c("DEU", "COD", "BFA"),
  malaria = c(1, 1, 2))

## Re-merge
malMap <- joinCountryData2Map(malDF, joinCode = "ISO3",
  nameJoinColumn = "country")

## Specify the colourPalette argument
mapCountryData(malMap, nameColumnToPlot="malaria", catMethod = "categorical",
  missingCountryCol = gray(.8), colourPalette = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much, this really helped me... still got a few of the small African countries that don't appear on the map but that shall be another days task!

Comment: Do you know a possibility to make 2 groups? ie: c("DEU", "COD") in red and c("BFA") in blue?

Comment: @TeYaP, I just added an example with two colors

Comment: Do you know how should I zoom on a particular zone (eg. Europe or Africa)?

Comment: @AndreaM, you can set the `mapRegion` argument in the `mapCountryData` function to something like `"Africa"` or use the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments to set the map extents.

Answer (score 14):

Try using googleVis package and use gvisGeoMap Functions

e.g.

```
G1 <- gvisGeoMap(Exports,locationvar='Country',numvar='Profit',options=list(dataMode='regions'))

plot(G1)
```

Comment: Wow, I never realized how powerful googleVis is!  Very simple syntax, no need to worry about spatialPointsDataFrame's, and the output is beautiful!

Answer (score 11):

```
    library(maptools)
    data(wrld_simpl)
    myCountries = wrld_simpl@data$NAME %in% c("Australia", "United Kingdom", "Germany", "United States", "Sweden", "Netherlands", "New Zealand")
    plot(wrld_simpl, col = c(gray(.80), "red")[myCountries+1])
```

[image]