# Adding color to the country based on the color values from the Column B

Tags: r

I have a data set `temp`, as below.

```
temp = data.frame(Country = c("France","Isreal","INDIA"),
                   Color = c("Green","Red","BLUE"))


Country   Color
France    Green
Isreal    Red
INDIA     BLUE
```

I would like to color these countries in Column A (Country) on the world map with the Column B(Color) values using R. Say for example, India should be represented by the color Blue as in Column B.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233020/1534346

Comment: Hi Romain, Thanks for the reply. What I am looking for is, for countries in column A(Country) I want it to be colored based on the Column B (Color). ie. Say for example if Country is France I want it to be represented by Green color on the map, similarly for India is should be Blue.