# Adding points to represent cities on a World Map using rworldmap

Tags: r, rworldmap

I want to make a world map with specific countries filled in, but if possible I'd like to also include pinpoints representing specific cities on the countries.

I've been using the `rworldmap` package and experimenting with others but I'm having a hard time understanding how to pinpoint specific city locations and where to include the `mapbubbles` for the pinpoint.

Maybe I could add a line like this, representing San Diego, but I don't know where it would go:

```
mapBubbles(dF="CEAMap", nameX = "-117.16", nameY = "32.71", nameZSize = "CEAMap",)
```

I've been reading the developer's PDF and I honestly can't really understand how to implement the map bubbles and what things like nameZsize are supposed to contain in the first place.

I used this guide to learn how to highlight the countries, but as far as pinpointing the cities, it looks like I'm on my own because I can't really understand the developer's PDF.
[How to create a world map in R with specific countries filled in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225343/how-to-create-a-world-map-in-r-with-specific-countries-filled-in)

Here is my full code so far:

```
library(rworldmap)
library(ggmap)
library(maptools)
library(maps)

theCountries <- c("USA", 
                  "CAN", "DEU", "FRA", "IND", 
                  "GBR", "NLD", "ITA", 
                  "CHN", "KOR", "JPN", 
                  "ESP", "PRT", "RUS", 
                  "NOR", "SGP", "AUS", 
                  "CHL", "MEX", "PHL", "RWA", 
                  "JOR", "HND", "PAN", "THA", "DOM", 
                  "ZAF", "TUR", "CHE", "FIN",
                  "SEN", "BOL", "OMN", "PAK", "CMR", "MUS", "BEL", "MYS", 
                  "UAE", "BRA", "MLI", "MOZ", "NAM", "EGY", "ARG", "UKR", "ZMB", "KEN",
                  "VNM", "NGA", "DNK", "IRN", "AFG")
# These are the ISO3 names of the countries you'd like to plot in red

CEAMap <- data.frame(country = c("USA", 
                                 "CAN", "DEU", "FRA", "IND", 
                                 "GBR", "NLD", "ITA", 
                                 "CHN", "KOR", "JPN", 
                                 "ESP", "PRT", "RUS", 
                                 "NOR", "SGP", "AUS", 
                                 "CHL", "MEX", "PHL", "RWA", 
                                 "JOR", "HND", "PAN", "THA", "DOM", 
                                 "ZAF", "TUR", "CHE", "FIN",
                                 "SEN", "BOL", "OMN", "PAK", "CMR", "MUS", "BEL", "MYS", 
                                 "UAE", "BRA", "MLI", "MOZ", "NAM", "EGY", "ARG", "UKR", "ZMB", "KEN",
                                 "VNM", "NGA", "DNK", "IRN", "AFG"),
                      involvement = c(1, 
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                    3, 3, 3, 
                                    4, 4, 4, 
                                    5, 5, 5, 
                                    6, 6, 6, 
                                    7, 7, 7, 7,
                                    8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
                                    9, 9, 9, 9,
                                    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
                                    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
                                    12, 12, 12, 12, 12))

# CEAMap is a data.frame with the ISO3 country names plus a variable to
# merge to the map data

CEAcountries <- joinCountryData2Map(CEAMap, joinCode = "ISO3",
                              nameJoinColumn = "country")


# This will join your CEAMap data.frame to the country map data

mapCountryData(CEAcountries, nameColumnToPlot="country", 
               catMethod = "categorical",
               mapTitle='CEA Locations',
               missingCountryCol = gray(.8))
```

I'd like to have specific points highlighting cities on the filled in countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to have specific points highlighting cities on the filled in
>   countries.

Then `mapBubbles()`is the wrong function. You can just add `points()` as in a regular R-plot.

Get the location data of the cities before:

```
library(maps)

data("world.cities")

plotcities <- subset(world.cities, capital == 1)
```

I don't know which cities are of interest to you, so I took just the capitals

```
mapCountryData(CEAcountries, nameColumnToPlot="country", 
               catMethod = "categorical",
               mapTitle='CEA Locations',
               missingCountryCol = gray(.8), addLegend = FALSE)
points(plotcities$long, plotcities$lat, pch =  18, col = "black")
```

[image]

I recommend looking at packages like `tmap` though. They make much nicer maps. `ggplot2` might be a better choice, too.

**EDIT:** To use the citys you provided just select accordingly:

```
plotcities <- subset(world.cities, 
                     name %in% c("Cologne", "Chennai", "Denver", "Madrid", "Manila", "San Diego", "Seattle", "Shanghai")
                     & country.etc %in% c("Germany", "USA", "Spain", "China", "Philippines", "India"))
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for informing me that mapbubbles is the wrong function. I'd like to highlight the cities: "Cologne", "Chennai", "Denver", "Madrid", "Manila", "San Diego", "Seattle", "Shanghai". How would I go about plotting them on the map in this case? Thanks for the help

Comment: If the plot is okay for you, you just have to select the cities from `world.cities`. I have made an update.