# How to generate a country map with specific regions filled in

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, shapefile, r-sf

I'm trying to create a country map with specific regions filled in. I want to  divide the country in 3 categories: extreme, high, too high.  So in each category there will be a number of regions(DEPARTAMEN). Each category should have a specific color (black, red, orange). Let's say , for example, in extreme category there will be 8 regions(DEPARTAMEN) with the same color (black).

The first answer is exactly what I want, but I couldn't do the same because I can´t use the rworldmap package in this case: [How to create a world map in R with specific countries filled in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225343/how-to-create-a-world-map-in-r-with-specific-countries-filled-in).  In the first answer they used rworldmap fuctions  to join maps, and to fill regions by category.

This is how my data looks like (shp file):

```
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -79.45845 ymin: -17.28501 xmax: -70.80408 ymax: -2.986125
geographic CRS: WGS 84
  IDDPTO DEPARTAMEN     CAPITAL FUENTE                       geometry
1     01   AMAZONAS CHACHAPOYAS   INEI MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.81211 -...
2     02     ANCASH      HUARAZ   INEI MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.64692 -...
3     03   APURIMAC     ABANCAY   INEI MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.74632 -...
4     04   AREQUIPA    AREQUIPA   INEI MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.98109 -...
5     05   AYACUCHO    AYACUCHO   INEI MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.34843 -...
6     06  CAJAMARCA   CAJAMARCA   INEI MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.70034 -...
```

Is there a way  to do the same as the answer chosen in this question ([How to create a world map in R with specific countries filled in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225343/how-to-create-a-world-map-in-r-with-specific-countries-filled-in)) but without using rworldmap package? Also I'm using ggplot package to plot the map.

This is my desired output:
[image]

Comment: This appears to be a question for which I have seen answers on StackOverflow and on the WWW. It also does not appear to have a reproducible example. You should do a search first and if the answer is not forthcoming investigate then search SO how to present a question with a [MCVE].

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You might need to get the shapefile with Perú's departments somewhere. Then join a dataset with the values of your thresholds.
Packages tidyverse() and sf() will handle the taks easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could merge a dataframe (i.e. `left_join()`) with the categories you need into your sf object.
As I do not have your shapefile, I get a similar one with the help of `raster::getData()`.

I manually create a dataframe called "example_data" with, as per your request, Lima, Ancash, and Amazonas, with "extreme" values, and randomly assign "very high" or "high" to the rest of the departments.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(raster)

sf_peru <- raster::getData("GADM", country ="PE", level =1) %>% sf::st_as_sf()

example_data <- tibble(
  departamentos = sf_peru$NAME_1,
  risk = sample(x = c('very high', 'high'), 
                   size = length(sf_peru$NAME_1), 
                   replace = TRUE )) %>% 
  mutate(risk = if_else(departamentos %in% c("Lima", "Amazonas", "Ancash"), true = "extreme", false = risk))

sf_peru_joined <-  sf_peru %>% left_join(example_data, by = c("NAME_1" = "departamentos"))
custom_colour_scale <- c("extreme" = "red", "very high" = "orange", "high" = "yellow")

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = sf_peru_joined,
          aes(fill = risk)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colour_scale,
                    limits = c("extreme", "very high", "high"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , it was really helpful. But It is not clear to me how to group the departments. For example, I would like Lima, Amazonas, Ancash to belong to the extreme category and to be filled with red. Where in the code could that go?

Comment: You could create a dataframe that holds those values. Replace my dataframe "random_data" with that "true_data" df.