# Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE when using fortify function, rgdal package

Tags: r, rgdal

I am trying to work with spatial data that I downloaded [here](http://www.cbs.nl/nl-NL/menu/themas/dossiers/nederland-regionaal/links/2013-buurtkaart-shape-versie-1-el.htm) in order to make a map in ggplot2.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)
df <- readOGR(mydirectory, layer = 'gem_2013_v1')
df.fort <- fortify(df, region = "AANT_INW")
```

I keep on getting this error when using the function fortify:

```
Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE
```

Has anyone an idea about what's going wrong here? Most appreciated!

**EDIT:**

As mentioned in the comments a possible duplicate of this question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093399/how-to-turn-gpclibpermit-to-true). It is stated that the solution of the problem can be found in installing package gpclib. I am not sure if that's the case, this package has been removed from CRAN.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn gpclibPermit() to TRUE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093399/how-to-turn-gpclibpermit-to-true)

Comment: @hrbrmstr I am not sure if that's the case. Installing and running package gpclib would be the answer to my question, but gpclib is not on CRAN anymore so I noticed. I will add this to my question.

Comment: You can install `rgeos` library and recompile `rgdal` and `ggplot`, and I think it works! as said by @hrbrmstr it's a comon issue :-)

Comment: I have installed rgeos. I guess I have to find out how now :-). But thanks for the comments anyway!

Comment: gpclib is on CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpclib/index.html

Comment: Hi- did you ever solve this? I am experiencing a similar issue

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue after upgrading R. I reinstalled `rgdal` and all was good.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I had to install gpclib. I'm not sure if when you made the update it was removed from CRAN, but it's there now. It must be installed from source so you'll have to use the following code:

```
install.packages("gpclib", type = "source")
```

Note that to install with this code you'll need to have the appropriate version of [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed.